# Should post flags and comment flags be treated differently for the Deputy and Marshall badges?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, badges, comment-flags

At present, comment and post flags are treated equally for the purpose of earning the Deputy (80 helpful flags) and Marshal (500 helpful flags) [badges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges). However it is *significantly* easier to get a helpful comment flag (for example, just flag almost any comment with the word "thanks" in it and you will instantly get a helpful flag) than to get a helpful post flag. In fact it was jokingly suggested on [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) today:

> How to get thousands of flags: Go through either Jon Skeet's or Gordon
> Linoff's answers and flag the thank you comments.

Given that post flags - for spam, rude/abusive, duplicate, not an answer, very low quality etc. - to my mind, have a *far* greater effect on the overall quality of the site (removing bad questions and/or answers greatly increases the value of the site to a user compared to removing a "thanks" or other chatty comment) it seems that helpful post flags should have more weight in terms of earning those badges than helpful comment flags.

This could perhaps be implemented by:

- making the requirements for a badge harder based on comment flags, e.g. the Deputy badge might take 80 helpful post flags but some multiple of that e.g. 3x i.e. 240 helpful comment flags to earn; or
- not counting "no longer needed" comment flags (I think these are the flags that have the least benefit to users of the site when marked helpful) towards the badge; or
- having separate badges for each type of flag, with the comment badges harder to earn

Comment: BTW, I said that in SOCVR as a joke. I wasn't saying cheating is correct. But nevertheless, I agree that this is neccessary :)

Comment: @10Rep I completely understand it was a joke, but it reinforces the point I am trying to make. If you would prefer I remove the quote I will do so. I have added the word "jokingly" to the post to clarify that.

Comment: @10Rep also, under the current "rules" for earning flag badges, it is absolutely not cheating. Gaming the system perhaps...

Comment: I think you're overthinking this. Post Marshall having 1 flag more or 1000s of flags more are both the same. A lot of people who try to game things stop once they reach Marshall, and yes, a lot of people do game stuff for flags. This includes reputable members of the community (and some are even mods on other sites!). The same goes with Steward, a lot of users just stop reviewing once they hit 1000 reviews. There's no need to prevent people from going hard on some tasks, just for badges, as they'll naturally stop once they get it (as long as they're not doing anything bad/illegal)

Comment: @BhargavRao I'd use that as an argument for having separate badges or requiring more comment flags to achieve a badge, at least then you will get better value for the site out of the people who stop once they get the badge.

Comment: Hah, that's one way to handle this.

Comment: @BhargavRao That argument also doesn't apply to people who flag not for badges, but for that number of helpful flags. Some people want to have a high amount of helpful flags, which is a good contribution to the site, but there's a chance to make it even more of a contribution. For instance, if post flags where worth 3 flags, and comment flags worth one, imagine this hypothetical persons reaction. They would immediately start flagging posts, instead of only focusing on comments.

Comment: If a user's intent is "good contribution to the site", @10Rep, then they'd already be doing that and not just increase the number of helpful flags.

Comment: I agree with @BhargavRao. Removing *"Thanks"* comments is a good thing... If someone is doing this just to *"game the system"* then they are also likely to remove comments that fall under the other categories (abusive language etc) while they are looking for the said *"thanks"* comments... So IMHO this is good for the site either way!

Comment: @Yatin I'm not saying that removing "thanks" comments is a bad thing, just that it adds a *lot* less value to the site than anything else you can get a helpful flag for, and I think people who remove 600 "thanks" comments don't deserve the same badge as someone who contributes to removing 600 NAA/VLQ/spam/... posts.

Comment: *"having separate badges for each type of flag"* I like this idea... And as @Nick said we can make NAA/VLQ/spam batches more "respectable" or "rewarding" by *maybe* awarding some rep. with them too (of course, the # of flags will be higher for these categories)

Comment: @BhargavRao there's nothing wrong with *"meeting a quota"* and moving on to other endeavors. That's neither gaming the system nor cheating, just *"meeting a quota"*.

Comment: True, @bad_coder, it isn't cheating. I didn't call it as such. Moving on after getting a badge isn't gaming either, I've been guilty of it too! Gaming is when they use quick and not so clean methods to achieve that goal.

Comment: @Yatin _maybe awarding some rep. with them too_ --> I'm in. But at the same time, it could lead to some abuse of the flagging system. For instance, sock puppets posting Spam answers and then main account flagging them to get reputation.

Comment: Comment flags don't count on Samuel's [Mod Flagger Stats](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/ModFlaggerStats.user.js) user script ;)

Comment: I think I have less than 10 comment flags and about 2500 post flags due to the above mentioned user script. We're all gaming the system in each our way. I'm not going to imply gaming is a good thing, but having a goal is a driver.

Comment: @Scratte I think you're probably the opposite of most. If everyone was like you I would never have asked this question...

Comment: @Scratte I have 86 comment flags, with the majority of them being "Unfriendly or Unkind". I only have like 4 or 5 no longer needed flags. I actually think this is pretty rare, a user flagging thanks comments since you can't find comments with a filter.

Answer (score 2):

> (...) significantly easier to get a helpful comment flag (...) than to get a helpful post flag.

This is seemingly true (in most cases) only because the approval is swifter. But the reverse argument can be made, that some post flags are no-brainers (NAA, VLQ, Blatantly off-topic, Caused by typo, etc) while sifting through a comment exchange ascertaining what should be kept can be mind boggling. (The mods are the first to say this, that: "Comments are harder to moderate than posts" - and that's why comments are disabled on certain posts.)

> post flags (...) have a far greater effect on the overall quality of the site

This overlooks the headache of reading a long exchange of comments trying to determine if something is relevant. While post flags reduce search results, comment flags reduce reading time of a given post.

> This could perhaps be implemented by:

Essentially badges serve to encourage use of functionality.

The 2 tangible gains would be:

- encouraging more flags (implicitly raising the overall flag quota - by weighted sum).
- establishing an additional distinction (explicitly adding more badges - thus quotas.)

In any case, establishing this kind of distinction is typical of a specific mentality - the *"curator"* mind set. Who's become so embroiled in the systems daily operations, he actually finds a sense to digress over minutiae.

What makes a curator *"tick"* in the long run, is the objective need of the task he voluntarily executes (well past any quotas - be they comment or post). And in that sense, he's a plumber ["Whose job is to clear the pipes, and keep sludge moving."](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsFvglP3mew&t=1m8s)