# How can I earn the Marshal badge faster?

Tags: discussion, flags, helpful-flags, flag-badges

The Marshal badge's requirements are 500 helpful flags. I have 244.

Based on my calculations, the average helpful rate right now on my flags is about 0.682. This means I will need to flag 782 flags to get the Marshal flag. If I raise 2 flags per day, it will take about 13 months to get the flag. (that's longer than a *year!*)

How can I get it faster?

1. Raise flags more
2. Increase the rate of acceptance
3. Other

Comment: *Fast* is not a good motivation. Just for your reference: My helpful rate is 0.96 over 5507 flags (post flags that is, 0.97 overall (13K flags)). What on earth are you flagging that you get so many declined?

Comment: Not declined flags, I have only 17 on post flags. But sometimes I get disputed or "gone away" flags. I know I am going to get heavily downvoted sooner or later, so just saying.

Comment: Please don't ignore your real problem: What on earth are you flagging that you collect so many not helpful flags.

Comment: 17 DECLINED flags. I guess I can't say anything without getting downvoted. I am mostly flagging questions for closure. That's it.

Comment: Don't flag just to get a badge - you will get in due course. Badges are for the "feel good" (well, and some are in part for running in mod election) part of things, just like a medal is. One doesn't ask "how do I get an Order of Merit faster", one earns it via exceptional service. Same here.

Comment: I have 9 declined post flags out of approximately 5600. So it's certainly possible to do better.

Comment: You don't seem to have any consideration for the moderators, who are all volunteers, that have to process your useless flags. Your flagging motivation should be about site quality, not about your reputation. Stop overloading the system with time consuming garbage yourself

Comment: If I could, I would give you the badge now so you can stop flagging ... what other badges you want, let me give all of them to you so you can feel good and stop your actions ..

Comment: I have a 99 percent flagging rate. I focus mostly on quality rather than quantity,

Answer (score 21):

> This means I will need to flag 782 flags to get the Marshal flag.

No, you need 500 **helpful** flags. Don't focus on quantity, focus on quality! Please, focus on quality of your moderation effort. If you can't bring that to the table then please refrain from flagging.

> If I raise 2 flags per day, it will take about 13 months to get the flag. (that's longer than a year!)

It took me longer than a year to get that badge. Still don't have it here on Meta.

You can raise 10 flags per day for sure and with each 10 helpful flags you get an one extra flag per day. So given your current flag count of 244 that is at max 25 days. One month worth of *good* flagging.

That is pretty fast. It doesn't need to go much faster.

Answer (score 6):

## How to raise more flags

To raise more flags you need to look for flaggable stuff. The easiest are probably comment flags since if you open any 2-day-old question there's likely to be some comments that are no longer needed. There's plenty of comments under accepted answers. "Glad it worked", "please upvote/accept", "I edited the answer" and so on...

If you want to flag more posts then you can search for Not An Answer or Very Low Quality answers (they're the same thing). Here again, you can find some if you look at older questions rather than the newly posted ones. If you are under 3k you can also flag questions from Triage queue or from the homepage/newest-first. Flag all questions that should be closed and this will send a post for a review.

There are also initiatives like [Charcoal](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11540/charcoal-hq), [SOBotics](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111347/sobotics) or even [my own room for NAAs](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210133/naabot). These are the places where users run bots that monitor low-quality posts and you can easily find something to flag there.

When it comes to NAAs, some of them can be found using keyword searches. Just search Stack Overflow for phrases that are unlikely to appear in answers and use `is:a` modifier. e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=%22please+help+me%22+is%3aa&mixed=0

## How to increase rate of acceptance

To make sure that your flags are mostly helpful you need to understand what content is flaggable and why. You can find plenty of such information here on Meta which will give you advice specific to Stack Overflow, but there is also Meta.StackExchange.com which has broader instructions. e.g. [How do I properly use the "Not an Answer" flag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185073/how-do-i-properly-use-the-not-an-answer-flag)

Learn from your declined flags. Why was the flag declined? Could it have been only in a need of an edit? If you flagged NAA then are you sure it was not just a really bad attempt at answering?

If you flagged Spam or Rude/Abusive, are you sure the reason is clear why you flagged it? The same goes for custom reasons. Are you sure you explained clearly why you bring this to the attention of moderators?

## Other

Don't just flag to get the badge. The badge is pretty meaningless. Flag to make this site better and make it easier to find useful information here. **Improve rather than flag** whenever possible.

Comment: If you're between 500 and 3k rep, you can find loads of posts to flag in the Triage, First Posts and Late Answers review queues.

Comment: "The easiest are probably comment flags" which is exactly why I posted [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/401892/should-post-flags-and-comment-flags-be-treated-differently-for-the-deputy-and-ma)