# Looks like the reviewers rejected my suggested edits. (Part 1?)

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

So I wanted to try and fix the titles of older Stack Overflow questions, to clarify the meaning better.

Turns out only 3 edits of mine are approved, while the rest have been rejected, and 1 is still pending (as of the writing of this question).

The reasoning for the rejects is:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

It actually confused me why this is the reason, as what I did was to clarify the question by editing the title.

An example would be this:

[image: Filling a DataSet or DataTable from a LINQ query result set]

What's funnier is that only 1 would approve while the rest won't. I'm not saying I'm objecting their opinions, but I'm curious why so.

I looked further from a rejection note, and I thought of this:

> Wait, if I edit the title and making it a bit longer, then my edit would be rejected because of the same reason.

But then, I remembered [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27737561). It got longer, but accepted.

I think the criteria that's left to deal with is "more accurate or more accessible".

So given this question's title: [Difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14/difference-between-math-floor-and-math-truncate)

How can I improve it? (My previous suggestion was "What's the difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate()?")

> If you want to check out my other edits, go to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14723686/henry-willies?tab=activity) and choose Suggestions.

Comment: For the question you have given an image of, what about that edit would you suggest is not *"completely superfluous"*?

Comment: @Larnu Check my pending edit. There's a good way on not being "*completely superfluous*".

Comment: @Larnu questions titles are best if they look like... questions.

Comment: @Braiam True, that's how I phrased them. However, in Question 25, it got rejected, and my only edit was adding a "?" at the end. Not sure if that is "*superfluous*" though.

Comment: Though I don't disagree with that, @Braiam , that doesn't make the change not superfluous; especially when the question is 12 years old.

Comment: I wasn't disputing that, @HenryWillies . If I was doing the review, I would be marking it as superfluous too.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255909/should-question-titles-generally-be-questions

Comment: @Larnu :| Okay...

Comment: I do not see any improvement from "Difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate()" to "What's the difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate()?" whatsoever. It's a Question, so obviously the question is what is the difference. The title is just the title. We don't need all posts to end with a question-mark.

Comment: There's irony in an edit comment of "Rewrote the title as some actual question" when this post has a title decidedly not a question.

Comment: @janw That's something I'm looking forward to that.

Comment: Oddly, the question actually had that title and [was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16/9) 8 years ago

Comment: @HenryWillies It is. No one cares about the "?".

Comment: Who are "they" @HenryWillies ..?

Comment: And plus, the title does NOT have to have a question mark next to it.

Comment: @zixuan I know. janw already suggested a related question, so I'm following that format.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a question either. "Difference between Math.Floor() and Math.Truncate()" is good enough. Adding the question does NOT make the question more accessible.

Comment: I hope this can be Part 1 and the  Final Chapter in one go ....

Comment: @rene I'll just hope I won't get disappointed with the rejections I get next time, otherwise there'd be a Part 2.

Comment: Remember, quality is better than quantity. Says the guy who tried to get the Marshal badge fast.

Comment: @zixuan Who's that?

Comment: Obviously me. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402572/how-can-i-earn-the-marshal-badge-faster

Comment: @zixuan And rene answered it as well.

Comment: @HenryWillies there is a help article on [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing) and Meta has an [FAQ post on Editing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303219/how-do-i-make-a-good-edit) and if that still leaves questions the [Uber Meta has an FAQ on suggested-edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work). I can't imagine that if you follow all the advice found there and research a bit more here on Meta that you make similar mistakes again. It is not that we don't have guidance, it is not easy discoverable.

Comment: @HenryWillies - Focus on helpful complete edits and you won’t be disappointed with the fact your edit proposals are rejected. A trivial edit like adding a question mark to the question title shouldn’t be the only substantial helpful legitimate change to a question when making an edit proposal

Comment: The ***How ... to?*** form is too illiterate. Either drop the question mark or use [standard QUASM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4yWEt0OSpg&t=1m49s).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Those are [all awful edits](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14723686/henry-willies?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) that don't make the question even a tiny bit easier to read.

You invite two people to review your edit, and then all you have on offer is [a question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/27749474) at the end of the title? How does that make the question better to understand? Better findable?

We're happy to take your suggestions but please make substantial edits to the body of the post as long as you don't have full edit privileges. Refrain from trivial title or tag only edits if you have nothing substantial to improve in the post body<sup>1</sup>.

There are plenty of fresh posts that come in that need love and editing assistance in the post body. Spelling, grammar, layout, code markdown, removing fluff and other pleasantries, you name it. The posts that haven't been touched for years really can do without that single character fix or marginal improvement.

Worth mentioning that the suggested edit queue has limited slots. Flooding that queue with minor stuff on older posts is preventing substantial improvements to be submitted for fresh content by other editors. That is not optimal.

---

1. [citation for @Braiam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A578411+edit+substantial)

Comment: "You invite three people to review your edit" two.

Comment: "Refrain from title or tag only edits if you have nothing substantial to improve in the post body." [citation needed] Title edits are the best edits because they help with discoverability!

Comment: @Braiam Not exactly invite, I just suggested edits, not invite them. Also, I might make a question on [Anatoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376618/anatoly) as he's the one who keeps on approving my edits, yet lost to 2 other people.

Comment: @Braiam let's just give the best advice for this OP at this moment in time. While your advice might be true it doesn't look like they will be able yet to make edits to titles that will get approved. And the rejections are the bit that bothers them. Write a competing answer if you know how to successfully fix their title only edits.

Comment: Putting yourself in the citation. Classy :)

Comment: [We got rid of the too minor reject reason for the same reason rene.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/238039/213575) What's  a "substantial" edit? Is there a metric agreed by *everyone*? You know that I would disagree that a title only edit is non-substantial, so we are back to the good old "lets remove non-substantial reject reason too".

Comment: BTW, your citation aren't good. Most of them aren't even related to what I quoted: **Refrain from** title or tag only **edits if you have nothing substantial to improve in the post body**. None of your posts refer to [title](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A578411+edit+substantial+title) or [tags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A578411+edit+substantial+tags) or [body](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A578411+edit+substantial+body) specifically.